# How to avoid child of child objects in Spring JPA?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-jpa

I am using Spring JPA.
I have three entities Student, ClassRoom and School like below

```
@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="name")
    private int age;

    ...
}

@Entity
public class ClassRoom implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private List<Student> students;

    ...
}

@Entity
public class School implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private List<ClassRoom> classRooms;

    ...
}
```

Now I am fetching **School** with **ClassRoom** details and I don't need Student details.

But Student entity in ClassRoom is set to Fetch Type EAGER. How can I get School records with ClassRoom records without Student records.

Note: I can't remove FetchType.EAGER on Student Entity.

Comment: First, your mapping doesn't make sense: your 2 ManyToOne should be OneToMany. EAGER does exactly the thing you don't want to do. So remove it. Why couldn't you?

Comment: Someone added EAGER in old code. Right now I can't remove

Comment: Yes, you can. Do it, fix all the code that relied on EAGER to work correctly, and there you go. I'm not saying it doesn't require work. But it's certainly possible.

Comment: Create a service that pulls data you want using native SQL, then pass the results through a custom mapper.  The results should be returned as an `Object[]`.  From there map it directly to the `Object` you want.  It's dirty, but gets you want you want.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a custom Repository then create a method inside either through an implementation of that interface or make the method `default`.  Here's an example of what those method(s) might look like (assuming you're going the implementation route):

```
public class SchoolRepositoryImpl implements SchoolRepository {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager em;

    public List<School> getSchoolById(Long schoolId) {
           Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select...");
           q.setParameter("schoolId", schoolId);
           List<Object[]> results = q.getResultAsList();
           return this.mapSchool(results);
    }

    private List<School> mapSchool(List<Object[]> entities){
            List<School> schools = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Object[] o : entities){
                  school s = new School();
                  s.set...
                  s.set...
                  schools.add(s);
            }
            return schools;
    }
}
```